# Android - ListView height determined by number of children

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have got a `ListView` and would like to set the height according to the number of children item it has got.

If the number < x, set to WRAP_CONTENT, and if the number >= x, set the height as a customized constant value, and make the `listView` scroll.

```
if (numberOfChildren > x) {
height = 100px;
 else {
   height = WRAP_CONTENT;
}
```

I have seen some post introducing `ViewTreeObserver`, but indeed i would like to know if there is any solution that is both functionally and practically correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LayoutParams` dynamically.

```
if (numberOfChildren > x) {
    listView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (100, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
else {
   listView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But for further enhancement, what if the height of the children is not constant but varied by their content? which the param `numberOfChildren` will then become `total height of children` ?

Comment: You can simply set height to wrap_content for that.

Comment: Side notes: `ListViewCompat` has got something like `measureHeightOfChildrenCompat()` which is also another approach.